# sublimetext vintage mode, vs VIM trying to find a substitute for a shortcut key

Tags: indentation, visual-mode

So in vim usually I press

```
v j j j > esc
```

then `gv` to reselect so that I can indent a couple of lines.

How can we reselect in VI?

Comment: If your reselecting to indent again, just use .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a plugin in Sublime text which.

Answer (score 2):

vi does not have a visual mode and hence does not have the maps `v`, `gv`, etc.

More precisely, in vi (the "visual" editor), the *normal* mode which you are in by default when starting vi is sometimes called visual mode.  In vim, this mode is always called normal mode whereas visual mode always refers to a distinct mode which allows text selection.  vi has no mode which corresponds to vim's visual mode.

There is at least one legacy usage of this previous terminology in vim- to leave ex mode (after pressing `Q`) you have to type `:visual` to return to normal mode.

Comment: Ok, Sorry I will edit the question to say I was using sublike text vintage mode